# How to deal with unknown variables in NSolve?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, code-review, code

I am trying to solve these equations by using NSolve and want to plot $p1^{2}+p2^{2}$ v/s P0. But there is some problem, it is showing running... but not showing any error. I don't know where I am doing wrong.
If anyone can solve this will be appreciated.

```
delta = -6;
gma = 0.01;
kb = 0.1;
kL = 0.1;
g0 = 1;
Pb = 1;
ome = 1;
nth = 2;
sol = NSolve[{2*P0*x2 - 2*Pb*(u2 - v2) - kL*p1 - 
      kb*(2*u1*x1 - 2*x2*u2 + 3*v1*x1 + 3*v2*x2 + 2*p1*y1 - 
         4*(x1^2 + x2^2)*y1) == 
     0, -kL*p2 + v1*x2 - kb*v2*x1 + 2*kb*p2*y1 == 0 , 
    2*g0*y2*p1 - 2*g0*y2*(x1^2 + x2^2) + 2*g0*u1*x2 + 2*g0*u2*x1 - 
      2*g0*v1*x2 + 2*v2*Pb + 2*u2*Pb - gma*q1 + gma*nth == 0, 
    2*g0*p2*y2 + 2*v2*x2 - gma*q2 == 0, 
    delta*u2 + ome*u2 + 
      g0*x2*(2*(p1^2 + p2^2) - (x1^2 + x2^2) - q1 + 3*y1^2 + y2^2) - 
      2*g0*x1*y1*y2 + g0*y2*(v1 + 2*u1) - g0*y1*(v2 + 2*u2) + 
      g0*(u1*y2 - u2*y1) + P0*y2 - Pb*(p2 - q2 - 2*x1*x2 - 2*y1*y2) - 
      kL*u1/2 - gma*u1/2 - kb*v1*y1/2 - kb*v2*y2/2 - kb*u1*y1/2 - 
      kb*u2*y2/2 - kb*(q1 - 2*(y1^2 + y2^2))*x1/2 - kb*q2*x2/2 - 
      kb*u1*y1 + kb*u2*y2 + kb*(y1^2 - y2^2)*x1 + kb*y1*y2*x2 == 
     0, -delta*u1 - ome*u1 + 2*x2*g0*y1*y2 + 
      x1*g0*(2*(p1^2 + p2^2) - (x1^2 + x2^2) - q1 + 3*y1^2 + y2^2) - 
      g0*(v1 + 2*u1)*y1 - g0*y2*(v2 + 2*u2) - g0*(u1*y1 + u2*y2) - 
      P0*y1 + Pb*(p1 - q1 + x1^2 - x2^2 - y1^2 + y2^2) - k1*u2/2 + 
      gma*u2/2 - 
      kb/2*(v1*y2 - v2*y1 - u1*y2 + u2*y1 + q2*x1 - 
         x2*(q1 - 2*(y1^2 + y2^2)) + 2*u1*y2 + 2*u2*y1 - 2*y1*y2*x1 + 
         x2*(y1^2 - y2^2)) == 
     0, -delta*v2 + ome*v2 - 
      g0*((2*p1 - (x1^2 + x2^2) + q1 - 2*(y1^2 + y2^2))*
          x2 + (2*p2 + q2)*x1) - 
      g0*((2*v1 - x1*y1 + x2*y2 + u1)*
          y2 + (2*v2 - x1*y2 - x2*y1 - u2)*y1) - g0*(v2*y1 - v1*y2) - 
      P0*y2 - Pb*p2 - Pb*q2 - 2*Pb*x1*x2 - 2*Pb*y1*y2 - kL*v1/2 - 
      gma*v1/2 - kb*v1 + kb/2*(x1*y1 - x2*y2) - kb/2*(u1*y1 + u2*y2) -
       kb/2*(q1 - 2*y1^2*x1 - 2*y2^2*x1 + v1*y1 + v2*y2) == 0, 
    delta*v1 - ome*v1 + 
      g0*((2*p1 - (x1^2 + x2^2) + q1 - 2*(y1^2 + y2^2))*x1 - 
         2*(p2 + q2)*x2) + 
      g0*((2*v1 - x1*y1 + x2*y2 + u1)*
          y1 - (2*v2 - x1*y2 - x2*y1 - u2)*y2) + g0*(v1*y1 + v2*y2) + 
      P0*y1 + Pb*p1 + Pb*q1 + Pb*x1^2 - Pb*x2^2 + Pb*y1^2 - Pb*y2^2 - 
      Pb - kL*v2/2 - gma*v2/2 - kb*v2 + kb/2*(x1*y2 + x2*y1) - 
      kb/2*(u1*y2 - u2*y1) - 
      kb/2*(q2 - 2*y1^2*x2 - 2*y2^2*x2 - v1*y2 + v2*y1) == 
     0, -delta*x2 - g0*(v2 - u2) - kL*x1/2 - kb/2*(u1 + v1) == 0, 
    delta*x1 + g0*(u1 + v1) + P0 + 2*Pb*y1 - kL*x2/2 - 
      kb*(v2 - u2)/2 == 0, 
    ome*y2 - g0*p2 - gma*y1/2 == 
     0, -ome*y1 + g0*p1 + 2*Pb*x1 - gma*y2/2 == 0}, {x1, x2, y1, y2, 
    u1, u2, v1, v2, p1, p2, q1, q2}];
Plot[{Evaluate[p1^2 + p2^2] /. sol}, {P0, 0, 30}]
```

Comment: Is the `k1` supposed to be `kL`?

Comment: @Bill Sir, Thankyou for comment, But it is still showing running.

Comment: If you set a certain value of `P0` does `NSolve` produce a solution?

Comment: @yarchik Sir, I set the value of P0=1, it is still running and no solution is produced.

Comment: @vidya There are 224-226 branches of solution for every `P0` including 13 reals for `p0=1`. So your problem is incorrect. You can try to plot minimal real branch for instance.

Comment: @Sir, I have minimized the equations but it is still showing running.